# How do I return a single value from an array output by a function without declaring a variable first?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have this:

```
function data() {
    $out['a'] = "abc";
    $out['b'] = "def";
    $out['c'] = "ghi";
    return $out;
}
```

I can output the data by declaring it as a variable, then using the array index to echo it:

```
$data = data();
echo $data['a'];
echo $data['b'];
echo $data['c'];
```

But, I'm calling functions inline with other functions, and I'm trying to avoid having to declare a variable first. For instance, I want to do something like this:

```
echo data()[0]; //pulls first value in array without declaring it as a variable first. This needs to be variable i.e. data()[1] data()[2] etc.
```

Or more specifically, I'm actually trying to do it as a class:

```
$traverseXML->getData("Route", "incoming", "field", "value")[0] 
//getData() returns an array, I'm trying to get a single value.
```

Comment: Please rephrase. I do not understand what you are really asking for.

Comment: What you're asking is an available feature as of PHP5.4 http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Answer (score 0):

Personally i would do something like this

```
<?php 
function data($key = false, $default = 'not found') {
    $out['a'] = "abc";
    $out['b'] = "def";
    $out['c'] = "ghi";
    if($key)
    {
        if(isset($out[$key]))
            return $out[$key];
        else
            return $default;
    }       

    else
        return 'empty';
}
 ?>

 <?= data('a') ?>
```

Comment: so you supply the array index as a function argument - that's a pretty decent solution.

Comment: yeah, and with the $default argument the function will always return something, you won't be getting undefined index errors.